# Disciplining dunce hats

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, paper-request

I'm wondering if anyone has a copy of a preprint by Charles Giffen from 1977, with the enjoyable title, *Disciplining dunce hats in 4-manifolds*.  I've seen it referred to in various places, including the book, "Embeddings in Manifolds,", by Robert J. Daverman and Gerard Venema. That book explains at least some of the contents (which have to do with spines of 4-manifolds) but I'd be interested in seeing the original paper.